# Question on the continuity of a certain kind of evaluation map

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

I ran across a function in the proof of the Arzela-Ascoli Theorem and got stuck on proving the continuity of it:

Let $(C(X, Y), \rho)$ be the set of continuous functions mapping from $X$ to $Y$, $X$ is a topological space and $(Y, d)$ is a metric space, $\rho$ the sup metric corresponding to $d$. Define the function $\phi_x: C(X, Y) \to Y$ to be $\phi_x(f) = f(x)$.

Why is this function continuous?

Comment: Given $\varepsilon>0$, you want $\delta>0$ such that $\rho(f,g)<\delta\Rightarrow d(f(x),g(x))<\varepsilon$, which $\delta$ would you pick?

Comment: @Alan Ah this is silly. Simply choose $\delta = \epsilon$ would work, right?

Comment: Yes the map $\phi_x$ is a contraction for all $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that $$d(\phi_x(f),\phi_x(g)) = d(f(x),g(x))\le \rho(f,g)$$

for all $f,g$.